# ExtJS: how to insert a record of a store into another store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have two data models: `Writer.AttributValeur` and `Writer.Produit`.

`Writer.Produit` has one2man relationship with `Writer.AttributValeur`.

I want to display (and to create/edit/delete) a list of `Writer.Produit`. And I want to be able to add an `Writer.AttributValeur` to the current `Writer.Produit`.

So here's what I've done: two stores:

- the first one is linked with a grid (and a form) to display (and to create/edit/delete) a list of `Writer.Produit`.
- the second one is used to display a list (only a list) of `Writer.AttributValeur`

In the first grid, there's a button "Add `AttributValeur`". When the user clicks on it, I display a Windows where there's a grid linked with the second store. If the user selects a record, and click sur ok, I can get the `Writer.AttributValeur` record with this code:

```
var currentAttribut = gridAttributs.getView()
    .getSelectionModel()
    .getSelection()[0];
```

I want to add this record, `currentAttribut`, to the `Writer.Produit` store.

Any idea how to do this? Following is the ExtJS declaration of my data models, and creation of my stores.

```
Ext.define('Writer.AttributValeur', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },  
        'description',
        'val'
    ],  
    belongsTo: 'Writer.Produit'
});

Ext.define('Writer.Produit', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },  
        'titre',
        'description'
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'Writer.AttributValeur',
        name: 'attributs'
    }   
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Produit',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'json/liste_view/',
            create:  'json/item/?mode=create',
            update:  'json/item/?mode=update',
            destroy: 'json/item/?mode=destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});


var storeAttributs = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.AttributValeur',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'json/attributs/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be the problem? Each store has method `add`. Use it.

Comment: Ok I mark your question as "ok" because it answers to my question. My question was not well formed, I'll ask another one ;)